# Was the Elm language included as a choice in the 2018 survey?

Tags: discussion, survey-2018

I just looked over the results of the 2018 survey, and I noticed the Elm language, which has a growing and enthusiastic developer base, didn't place in any of the lists. Was this because there weren't enough respondents who picked it, or because it wasn't an available choice? If it wasn't a choice, is there a way for this community to make it a choice next time?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It was not available as a choice this year but I have just looked at the free response section (`"Are there any languages we should add to this list for next year?"`) and the number of people who suggested Elm was pretty substantial. We remove languages/frameworks/databases from previous years that have very low response rates and add ones that many people suggest or that have gained prominence during that year (TensorFlow comes to mind as an example).

The overall goal is to keep the number of languages to scroll through as a survey respondent not *too* long. The best way for the community to suggest a choice is to take the survey and add it in the free response section for that question.